# Buttons Background Dynamically changed

Tags: java, swing

I have to change the background of a `JButton` on some action.

I have two classes.  The first one is an `Action` subclass and the second is a `GUI` class.

In the `GUI` class I have put buttons inside panels just like a matrix.

On some action, which is captured in the `Action` class, I want to inform the GUI class to change the background of a `JButton`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: assuming its home work i tagged it accordingly, if not please change.

Comment: Which background? The background on which the buttons reside or the background for each button? Do you want to change the color of the background or do some custom drawing or show a loaded image?

Comment: `I have changed Jbuttons background.` you have to show us (in the http://sscce.org/ form) your code, otherwise everything is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ or here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/CatalogSwing-JFC.htm

Comment: On some Look&Feel implementations, `button.setBackground()` has no apparent effect. Which are you using.

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to change your button background to blue. 
You do this:

```
 JButton button = new JButton("Click to Change Background");
 button.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```